# Crash - Ejabberd (21

Tags: java, android, ejabberd, smack

I have Ejabberd 21.01, recently upgraded, though that error/crash doesn't have any relevancy.  Just wondering if there is any configuration mismatch or client is sending garbage causing this crash?  Have been noticing this crash once in a while.  Got following log,

```
2021-02-09 13:55:46.536 [error] <0.31162.0> gen_server <0.31162.0> terminated with reason: bad return value: #{tls_options => [compression_none,{dhfile,<<"/etc/ssl/ejabberd/dh.pem">>}],mgmt_max_timeout => 300000,mgmt_pending_timer => #Ref<0.3896716666.2157707268.137537>,lserver => <<"server.one.com">>,stream_version => {1,0},mgmt_stanzas_in => 1271,mgmt_id => <<138,233,247,19,252,82,167,106>>,tls_enabled => false,user => <<"11888842">>,stop_reason => {socket,closed},mgmt_max_queue => 5000,codec_options => [ignore_els],mgmt_stanzas_out => 6615,stream_id => <<"6931452676501402135">>,csi_queue => {0,...},...}
2021-02-09 13:55:46.538 [error] <0.31162.0>@p1_server:terminate:878 CRASH REPORT Process <0.31162.0> with 0 neighbours exited with reason: bad return value: #{tls_options => [compression_none,{dhfile,<<"/etc/ssl/ejabberd/dh.pem">>}],mgmt_max_timeout => 300000,mgmt_pending_timer => #Ref<0.3896716666.2157707268.137537>,lserver => <<"server.one.com">>,stream_version => {1,0},mgmt_stanzas_in => 1271,mgmt_id => <<138,233,247,19,252,82,167,106>>,tls_enabled => false,user => <<"11888842">>,stop_reason => {socket,closed},mgmt_max_queue => 5000,codec_options => [ignore_els],mgmt_stanzas_out => 6615,stream_id => <<"6931452676501402135">>,csi_queue => {0,...},...} in p1_server:terminate/7 line 878
2021-02-09 13:55:46.538 [error] <0.913.0> Supervisor ejabberd_c2s_sup had child undefined started with {ejabberd_c2s,start_link,undefined} at <0.31162.0> exit with reason bad return value: #{tls_options => [compression_none,{dhfile,<<"/etc/ssl/ejabberd/dh.pem">>}],mgmt_max_timeout => 300000,mgmt_pending_timer => #Ref<0.3896716666.2157707268.137537>,lserver => <<"server.one.com">>,stream_version => {1,0},mgmt_stanzas_in => 1271,mgmt_id => <<138,233,247,19,252,82,167,106>>,tls_enabled => false,user => <<"11888842">>,stop_reason => {socket,closed},mgmt_max_queue => 5000,codec_options => [ignore_els],mgmt_stanzas_out => 6615,stream_id => <<"6931452676501402135">>,csi_queue => {0,...},...} in context child_terminated
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like team has posted a new commit to fix that issue.  That seems a little bug.

https://github.com/processone/ejabberd/issues/3524